# add new variable in task_struct (sched.h) spoils the mouse LINUX KERNEL

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mouse, scheduler

I am trying to create a new variable in the definition of task_struct in `sched.h` to use in my program. Once modified and compiled the mouse stops working.

In `/dev/input` it does not appear `mouse0`, although let me do `cat /mice` but this appears absolutely nothing.
I'm using virtual box, and shows that the mouse is reading correctly.

When I see the messages in the dmesg, `dmesg | grep mouse` shows me the following messages: `psmouse: About disagrees version of symbol module_layout`

```
struct task_struct {
volatile long state;    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
void *stack;
atomic_t usage;
unsigned int flags; /* per process flags, defined below */
unsigned int ptrace;
int tipo;//my variable
...
```

Should I change something else in some other file?

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125624/unable-to-load-module-disagrees-about-version-of-symbol-module-layout) . Your module is probably compiled using the old `task_struct`. Rebuilding the kernel and the modules should fix that ...

Comment: Thank you very much, now works perfectly.
PD. How should I close this question?

Comment: Normally, your comment, which clearly describes that problem is solved, is sufficient. You can also provide answer to the question ([selfanswer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) and accept it. Such way the question will be viewed at site as having accepted answer, which simplifies search of unanswered questions. So, this is preferred way. Also, by providing answer, you will gain reputation when someone upvote it(find it usefull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the modules, including which controll the mouse, are compiled using the old task_struct.

To fix this, you must recompile the modules, after compiling the kernel.

> make bzImage
>
> make modules
>
> make modules_install
>
> make install